# Smooth a binary variable using moving average or kernel smoothing

Tags: r, smoothing

I have data of the form:

```
x      y
0      0
0.01   1
0.03   0
0.04   1
0.04   0
```

`x` is continuous from 0 to 1 and not equally spaced and y is binary.

I'd like to smooth `y` over the x-axis using R, but can't find the right package. The kernel smoothing functions I've found produce density estimates of `x` or will give the wrong estimate at the ends of the x because they'll average over regions less than 0 and greater than 1.

I'd also like to avoid linear smoothers like Loess givens then binary form of `y`.  The moving average functions I've seen assume equally-spaced x-values.

Do you know of any R functions that will smooth and ideally have a bandwidth selection procedure?  I can write a moving average function and cross-validate to determine the bandwidth, but I'd prefer to find an existing function that's been vetted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using something like

```
d <- data.frame(x,y) ## not absolutely necessary but good practice
library(mgcv)
m1 <- gam(y~s(x),family="binomial",data=d)
```

This will (1) respect the binary nature of the data (2) do automatic degree-of-smoothness ("bandwidth" in your terminology) selection, using generalized cross-validation.

Use

```
plot(y~x, data=d)
pp <- data.frame(x=seq(0,1,length=101))
pp$y <- predict(m1,newdata=pp,type="response")
with(pp,lines(x,y))
```

or

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d,aes(x,y))+geom_smooth(method="gam",family=binomial)
```

to get predictions/plot the results.

(I hope your real data set has more than 5 observations ... otherwise this will fail ...)

Comment: Made a couple of edits. Hope you don't mind. Some example data (for anyone who wants to try out Ben's code) is: `set.seed(1); d <- data.frame(x=seq(0,0.3, by=0.01), y=rbinom(31, 1, prob=0.5))`.

Comment: To get uneven spacing, as in the question: `d <- data.frame(x=seq(0,0.3, by=0.01) + .009*rnorm(31), y=rbinom(31, 1, prob=0.5)`

Comment: Thanks Ben, Josh and Matthew.  I'm familiar with GLM's, but GAM's are new to me and I would never have thought of using them.

Comment: With my data, 15% of the x region has a predicted value greater than 1, even though y can't be greater than 1.  Is it valid to set all predicted values above 1 equal to 1?  Thanks.

Comment: are you already using the `type="response"` argument suggested in @JoshO'Brien's edit to my answer?

Comment: Thanks, Ben.  Using JoshO'Brien's correction fixes the problem.  For anyone else trying to model a similar data set, the cross-validated error for a moving average is lower than GAM's, however, both approaches are worth trying.

Comment: I have a very similar data set. What parameter in the s() function do you have to change to decrease the level of smoothing?

Comment: See `?s`, `?gam`, and/or Simon Wood's book. Or use `library(splines)`, use `ns()` instead of `s()`, and specify the number of knots manually.